# Symfony2: Default Form Type Guesser broken

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I somehow managed to break the default form type guesser of symfony 2.6. Let me show you some simple code:

ExampleType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('test')  // should be a text type because it's stored as string
        ;
    }

    ...

}
```

But when I call the form I get an uncaught PHP Exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType"" at /home/gv/PhpstormProjects/vcb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php line 83
```

Stack Trace:

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType"
at n/a
    in /home/gv/PhpstormProjects/vcb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php line 83

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry->getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType')
    in /home/gv/PhpstormProjects/vcb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 82

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->createNamedBuilder('test', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType', null, array('required' => false))
    in /home/gv/PhpstormProjects/vcb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 132

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->createBuilderForProperty('AppBundle\Entity\Example', 'test', null, array())
    in /home/gv/PhpstormProjects/vcb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 109

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->create('test', null, array())
    in /home/gv/PhpstormProjects/vcb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 267

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->resolveChildren()
    in /home/gv/PhpstormProjects/vcb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php line 215

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
    in /home/gv/PhpstormProjects/vcb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 39
```

It's no problem to circumvent this exception by explicitly passing the form type as second argument (in this example 'text') but I wonder what could stop the default form type guesser from working properly.

Any suggestions?

Greg

Comment: Seems like you ended up with a typeguesser for Symfony 2.8/3.0 instead of 2.6.

Comment: Hmm... If so, how would I fix it? I already deleted the whole symfony vendor folder and reinstalled symfony 2.6 by composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after all I don't know how I got things mixed up, but [clearing composer cache](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#clear-cache) before reinstalling symfony 2.6 did fix it.